# indice problem in array plz I don't find the answere anywhere else

Tags: python, arrays

I don't understand why my program keep returning

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`)   
and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I obviously have an integer in my array but it still give me the same error. I think this problem is pretty simple but I don't understand and I'm in quit a hurry so if someone could help me it would save me.

my program and the error :

```
def Mandelbrot(c):
    z=0
    zn = 0
    i = 0
    boo = True
    while boo == True and i < 50:
        if abs(zn) < 100:
            zn = z**2 + c
            boo = True
            z = zn
            i = i+1
        else : 
            boo = False
    return i

print (Mandelbrot(-2+1j*(-1.5)))

import math
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display_image
T=numpy.ndarray(shape=(500,500,3))
lig = -2
col = -1.5
while lig <=1:
    while col <= 1.5:
        c = lig + 1j * col
        v = Mandelbrot(c)
        print(v)
        if v < 50:
            u = False
        else:
            u = True
        print(int(u))
        T[lig][col]=[v]
        lig = lig + 0.001
        col = col + 0.001

display_image(T)
```

Comment: `T[lig][col]=[v]` and `lig` and `col` are floating point numbers ...

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: full error message (which you didn't show) probably shows you line `T[lig][col]=[v]` - so you could use `print( lig, type(lig),  col, type(col), v, type(v) )` to see what you have in variables. It expects `integer` values. BTW: don't expect that we will run code to see full error message

Comment: Thank you for your answeres, it's the first time I ask something on stack overflow so sorry for my errors and thank for the councelling. As you said the problem came from lig and col.